# Matlab dijkstra shortest path: list of nodes

Tags: matlab, nodes, dijkstra, shortest-path, adjacency-matrix

I would be really glad if you could suggest me a Matlab library containing functions that will allow me to list: 
1) all paths from a source to dest node on a network identified by its adjacency matrix
2) when applying dijkstra algorithm, I want to get the list of nodes not only the distance in terms of edges.

I already looked at this but it just provide with the shortest distance.

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a library, but 1) should be quite simple to write  by yourself.

If you want to analyse if you could reach one node from another node just calculate:

[image: Calculation of Reachability according to J. Lunze: Ereignisdiskete Systeme]

with the number of Nodes N, and the adjacency matrix G

the k-th matrix gives you information about the reachability in k-steps. If you use *syms* to name your edges in the matrix G, you will be able to identify all possible paths in the resulting matrix E.